# Jquery UI autocomplete inside MVC3 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hello i have this code in the controller :

```
   ViewBag.localitate = db.Localitatis.OrderBy(p => p.Localitate).ToList();
```

and on the view i try to get it via:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var availableTags = [
         @foreach (var item in ViewBag.localitate)
              {
                       @item.Localitate 
             }


    ];
        $("#destination").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

I din't know how to format this in order to get an array like in the jquery demo example :

```
"ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
```

in order to make the autocomplete work with my values from database,

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set your view data to only have the actual names you want:

```
ViewBag.localitate = db.Localitatis.Select(p => p.Localitate).OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
```

Then the simplest way to render this in javascript would be:

```
var availableTags = [" @String.Split("\,\"", ViewBag.localitate) "];
```

But I'd recommend using a JSON parser like JSON.NET instead. This way you don't have to worry about cross-site scripting attacks and such, since things are escaped for you.

```
var availableTags = @(JsonConvert.Serialize(ViewBag.localitate));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#destination").autocomplete({
            source: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.localitate))
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you have lots of data, consider using a server-side controller action to perform the filtering.